# Can't override preload because not function?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

Another .net newbie question

I created a class that inherits System.Web.UI.Page with the intention of overriding the preload and Unload functions.   But Visual Studios complains I can't override because "System.Web.UI.Page.PreLoad" is not a function.   What's wrong with my code?  Here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class BTPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected SqlConnection cnx;

    public override void PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cnx = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["btdatabase"]);
        cnx.Open();
    }

    protected void Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cnx.Close();
    }
}
```

If there's anything else alarming about my code, please tell me.  I'm new to .Net and I'm not sure if I'm doing things in the ".NET way".

What I also want to do is have every web page inherit from BTPage so that they all open a connection to the database on preload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PreLoad` is not a method of the `Page` type. You need to override `OnPreLoad`

Comment: Ok, I changed `PreLoad` to `OnPreLoad` and now I get this error: `'BTPage.OnPreLoad(object, System.EventArgs)': no suitable method found to override`.  Any ideas?

Comment: `OnPreLoad` is not an event subscription, but where the event is fired from, which means it doesn't have the `sender` argument.  You should change the method signature to `protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)`.